# Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac OSX El Capitan death on start up screen

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mac, macosx, refind

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have already installed rEFInd. But after I reboot and choose ubuntu drive, it gets stuck on the Ubuntu landing page. What am I missing?

[image: It's brick on this page.]

Answer (score 0):

I am no Unix wizard, in fact.. I am still an apprentice, I have just started my venture into the world of Unix. However... I myself have started messing around with an old MacBook (2006 LOL) of mine and tried wiping Mac OS X to replace it with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

From what I have learned in the process (still not finished yet... lots of research to do still), Apple computers seem to have a track record of being extremely finicky with operating systems that are not being emulated via BootCamp, Wine, etc. Majority of the time it's a driver/hardware issue.

All in all, I would start from square one and do some more research on your specific MacBook with Linux. I hope this gives some insight even though it's not an answer. Good luck!

**EDIT:** I found [this set](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/4x4691/help_dual_booting_on_a_mac/) of instructions on a reddit post. Seems pretty straight forward.

> 1. Install OSX.
> 2. With diskutil make a partition for ubuntu - a slice of your OSX drive.
> 3. Format a USB drive MBR FAT32. Install unetbootin on OSX, make bootable usb with it - use iso image and default settings.
> 4. Turn the computer off.
> 5. Start it holding option key. Mac's boot menu will apear - only now insert your ubuntu bootable USB, it should apear as EFI Boot. Hit return, then install.
> 6. When prompted on how to install, choose "something else", your partition is last on the list - sda1 is mac's recovery, sda2 is mac's root. Your partition will be sda5 or something. Delete the last partition, create a swap partition and a root partition. Choose your ubuntu root partition to install bootloader eg: dev/sda5, hit install.
> 7. When it finishes reboot. Don't panic let it boot into ubuntu. If ubuntu starts ok, turn the computer off.
> 8. Boot holding option, choose boot OSX (not recovery), when in OSX get refind, open terminal type sudo, drag the refind-install executable, hit enter, enter password, done. Reboot.
>
> If your OSX is El Capitan you need to disable csrutil before proceeding with refind.
>
> Works for me on Macbook Late 2009

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I completed these steps and I get stuck when boot to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed it by install 32 bit version. I don't know why it's not work on 64 bit version. My macbook is mid 2012, which is 64 bit.